# Biblatex equivalent to \adddot or \isdot for ellipsis?

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

In BibLaTeX, there is a command to turn a dot inserted in a reference into an abreviation dot, `\isdot`, allowing for a finer control of punctuation. There are also a variety of commands such as `\addperiod`, `\addcomma`, etc. for similar purposes. 
In some languages, bibliographic styles use ellipsis (…) to mark a short title, for instance

> J. Dupont, *Titre abrégé…*, p. 16.

or, without page reference,

> J. Dupont, *Titre abrégé…*

but not,

> J. Dupont, *Titre abrégé…*.

Is there a way to achieve this with BibLaTeX ?

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{shorttitle}{\textit{#1}\printtext{\dots\isdot}}
```

does not seem to work, and neither does,

```
\renewcommand{\bibfootnotewrapper}[1]{\bibsentence #1\adddot}
```

### Edit: MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.cbx}
\ProvidesFile{test.cbx}
\RequireCitationStyle{verbose}

\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{citetitle}{\textit{#1}\printtext{\dots}\isdot}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{citetitle}{\mkbibquote{#1\printtext{\dots}\isdot}}

%\renewcommand{\bibfootnotewrapper}[1]{\bibsentence #1\adddot}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bbx}
\ProvidesFile{test.bbx}
\RequireBibliographyStyle{verbose}

\end{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{akkerman_studien_1937,
    title = {Studien zum Karlmeinet: der dritte Abschnitt der Kompilation und sein Verh\"{a}ltnis zum ersten},
    shorttitle = {Studien zum Karlmeinet},
    author = {Jan Akkerman},
    year = {1937}
}

@article{dupont_2002,
    title = {Les chansons de geste: sous-titre particulièrement long que l'on va oublier},
    volume = {28},
    shorttitle = {Les chansons de geste},
    journal = {Revue de philologie romane},
    author = {Dupont, Jean},
    gender = {sm},
    year = {2002},
    pages = {3--22}
}

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, 
           style=test]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\footcite{akkerman_studien_1937} %OK

\footcite{dupont_2002} %OK 

\footcite[p.~50]{akkerman_studien_1937} %OK

\footcite[p.~50]{dupont_2002} %OK

\footcite{akkerman_studien_1937} %NOT OK

\footcite{dupont_2002} %OK

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Here is the problem I get after compiling:
[image: Extract from pdf showing the issue]

Comment: Can you show us a short [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) so we have something to play around with? Your question is quite clear without it, but really it will be easier for us to get started and to see if you have any peculiarities that could be a problem here.

Comment: Mhhh, I'm confused now, I just checked and I don't get a full stop after an ellipsis produced by `\dots`. I really need that MWE now.

Comment: Since its part of a full bibliographic style I am developing, I will need to reduce it a lot to produce a MWE, but I'm working on it.

Comment: Ok, I have added it to my question, with a capture showing the issue.

Comment: Interestingly, you will find that the issue arises only with `fontspec` and XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and not with pdfLaTeX.

Comment: Yes, and quite logically too, the (necessary) final dot after the quotes is suppressed too, but this can be corrected with `\midsentence` :
    `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{citetitle}{\mkbibquote{#1\printtext{\dots}\isdot\midsentence}}`
This looks like a BibLaTeX bug (or inconsistency). Maybe it would deserve a ticket on Github ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a difference in handling the ellipsis between the Unicode engines and pdfLaTeX. This discrepancy has been resolved in `biblatex` 3.10 (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/514, https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/5de1c77d639e4fdea5506bfdb3c90ec63be8c35c). Now all engines treat the ellipsis as if it were a sentence-ending full stop. If you use an older version, refer to the edit history for a solution.

You can now use `\isdot` to suppress full stops after an ellipsis, but allow commas.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{akkerman_studien_1937,
    title      = {Studien zum Karlmeinet: der dritte Abschnitt der Kompilation und sein Verh\"{a}ltnis zum ersten},
    shorttitle = {Studien zum Karlmeinet},
    author     = {Jan Akkerman},
    year       = {1937},
}

@article{dupont_2002,
    title      = {Les chansons de geste: sous-titre particulièrement long que l'on va oublier},
    volume     = {28},
    shorttitle = {Les chansons de geste},
    journal    = {Revue de philologie romane},
    author     = {Dupont, Jean},
    gender     = {sm},
    year       = {2002},
    pages      = {3--22},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
           style=verbose]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}\dots\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{citetitle}{\mkbibquote{#1\dots\isdot}}

\begin{document}
Lorem \footcite{akkerman_studien_1937} %OK
ipsum \footcite{dupont_2002} %OK
dolor\footcite[50]{akkerman_studien_1937} %OK
sit\footcite[50]{dupont_2002} %OK
amet\footcite{akkerman_studien_1937} %NOT OK
foo\footcite{dupont_2002} %OK
\end{document}
```

[image: footnotes of example document]

Comment: Many thanks ! It is starting to look good, but, as you will notice, the redefinition logically triggers capitalisation and suppresses following comma, when there is a following page reference (note 3). That's why we would need it to behave, in that regard, like an abreviation dot. If I understand the definition of `\addperiod` well, it should work like that: 
    \addperiod Adds a period unless it is preceded by an abbreviation dot or any other punctuation mark. This command may also be used to turn a previously inserted abbreviation dot into a period, for example at the end of a sentence.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteCamps Check the edit, please. It should work now, you indeed needed something like `\isdot`, but a bit more powerful. You don't want something like `\addperiod` here, since we only need to turn the ellipsis into a dot.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you, it works like a charm.

Comment: See also https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/514