# Biblatex - Multiple authors - 'and' should become '&' + DOT between title and publisher

Tags: biblatex, biber

Title says it all :)

My college has its own formatting rules so I need this to be pixel perfect :/

- The default output is author AND author. I need author **&** author
- The title of the book has to have a **DOT**, even when said title already ends with 3 of them.

Can somebody apply hers/his tex-fu on my problem? My college will be forever gratefull as I will be publishing my .sty file once I (yeah, this forum) has pretty much hacked all quircks..;

thank you !

references.bib

```
@book{valeriusNederlandtscheGedenckclanckKortelick1968,
  title = {Neder-Landtsche Gedenck-Clanck. {{Kortelick}} Openbarende de Voornaemste Geschiedenissen van de Seventhien {{Neder}}-{{Landsche}} Provintien, 't Sedert Den Aenvang Der Inlandsche Beroerten Ende Troublen, Tot Den Iare 1625. {{Verciert}} Met Verscheydene Aerdige Figuerlicke Platen, Ende Stichtelijke Rimen Ende Liedekens ... {{De}} Liedekens ... Gestelt Op Musycknoten ...},
  publisher = {{Amsterdam : Facsimile uitgaven Nederland}},
  author = {Valerius, Adrianus and Meertens, Pieter Jacobus and Tenhaeff, Nicolaas Bernardus and {Komter-Kuipers}, T},
  year = {1968}
}
```

document

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

% Biblatex
\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear,
            citestyle=authoryear,
            maxbibnames=99,              
            sortcites,                  
            giveninits=true,
            doi=false,
            isbn=false,
            dashed=false,
            backend=biber]{biblatex}
% end biblatex
\addbibresource{./bib/references.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{valeriusNederlandtscheGedenckclanckKortelick1968}

\newpage
\setquotestyle{british}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**Generated Output**

Valerius, A., P. J. Meertens, N. B. Tenhaeff en T. Komter-Kuipers (1968). *NederLandtsche Gedenck-Clanck - Op Musycknoten ...* publisher

[image]

**Desired Output**

Valerius, A., P. J. Meertens, N. B. Tenhaeff **&** T. Komter-Kuipers (1968). *NederLandtsche Gedenck-Clanck - Op Musycknoten*  **....** publisher

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. 1 is easily solved with

```
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}
```

For no. 2 I found it easiest to trick `biblatex` into adding a further full stop by adding `\@` after the `...` in the title. Normally `biblatex` suppresses double punctuation (or quadruple punctuation as would be the case here) when a dot or full stops meets another full stop.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,dutch]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,
            maxbibnames=99,              
            sortcites,                  
            giveninits=true,
            doi=false,
            isbn=false,
            dashed=false,
            backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{valeriusNederlandtscheGedenckclanckKortelick1968,
  title     = {Neder-Landtsche Gedenck-Clanck.
               {Kortelick} Openbarende de Voornaemste Geschiedenissen van de
               Seventhien {Neder}-{Landsche} Provintien, 't Sedert Den
               Aenvang Der Inlandsche Beroerten Ende Troublen, Tot Den Iare 1625.
               {Verciert} Met Verscheydene Aerdige Figuerlicke Platen,
               Ende Stichtelijke Rimen Ende Liedekens \dots{}
               {De} Liedekens \dots{} Gestelt Op Musycknoten \dots\@},
  location  = {Amsterdam},
  publisher = {Facsimile uitgaven Nederland},
  author    = {Valerius, Adrianus and Meertens, Pieter Jacobus
     and Tenhaeff, Nicolaas Bernardus and Komter-Kuipers, T},
  year      = {1968}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{valeriusNederlandtscheGedenckclanckKortelick1968}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Valerius, A., P. J. Meertens, N. B. Tenhaeff & T. Komter-Kuipers (1968). Neder-Landtsche Gedenck-Clanck. Kortelick Openbarende de Voornaemste Geschiedenissen van de Seventhien Neder-Landsche Provintien, ’t Sedert Den Aenvang Der Inlandsche Beroerten Ende Troublen, Tot Den Iare 1625. Verciert Met Verscheydene Aerdige Figuerlicke Platen, Ende Stichtelijke Rimen Ende Liedekens ... De Liedekens ... Gestelt Op Musycknoten .... Amsterdam: Facsimile uitgaven Nederland.]

Note that I used `\dots` instead of `...` to obtain the ellipsis symbol. If the ellipsis-period combination looks odd to you, you may want to try

```
Gestelt Op Musycknoten \dots\,\@
```

Normally

```
Gestelt Op Musycknoten ...\@
```

should be avoided. See [What is best method to insert an ellipsis in a (Xe)TeX document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73467/35864), you may also want to look into the [`ellipsis`](https://ctan.org/pkg/ellipsis) or [`xellipsis`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xellipsis) package.

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/340478/35864

Comment: Would you happen to have (a link to) a mini-tutorial on how to start _hacking_ tex-libraries like that?

Comment: @LooselySubtle Unfortunately, I know no tutorials for `biblatex` hacking. There are a few user-level tutorials at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864 that also mention some customisations, but other than that there is only https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864 and the many, many questions on this site (and other sites). If you are not afraid of code, you can always have a look at the standard styles (`biblatex.def`, `standard.bbx`) and see how things are defined.